# Google place API given wrong location for some places

Tags: angular, google-places-api

i have added google places API in my angular 6 project and it's working fine but in some search location showing pin on wrong location and given wrong lat log. search this address "**900 W Riverdale Rd, Ogden, UT, United States**" showing location with google places API in image 1. But when search in google give me accurate result in image 2.[image 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3QX5.jpg)

[image 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyCaC.jpg)

Comment: I notice that image 2 says Riverdale, UT and image 1 says Ogden, UT. Could this be due to the maps web interface auto-correcting an address, and the places API does not?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]